# How to check parameter value existence in a procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

The following is a procedure that uses 2 parameters: customer_code and pay_amount. 
The procedure works as expected, however when I enter wrong cus_code I get the error istead of my custom checking:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "XXXXX.CUST_PAY", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_pay (temp_ccode IN NUMBER, pay_amount IN NUMBER)AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    Value_check NUMBER;
    cbalance NUMBER;
      BEGIN
          SELECT Count(cus_code) 
          INTO value_check
          FROM customer
          WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

          IF value_check IS NULL THEN
              Dbms_Output.put_line('the value was not FOUND');
          ELSE
              UPDATE customer
              SET cus_balance = cus_balance - pay_amount
              WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

              SELECT cus_balance 
              INTO cbalance
              FROM customer
              WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

                IF cbalance < 0 THEN
                    Dbms_Output.put_line('The client owes us ' || cbalance);
                ELSE
                    Dbms_Output.put_line('Customer new balance is ' || cbalance);
                END IF;
        END IF;
     END;
  END;
```

What do I do wrong? I guest I need to check the value before I make SELECT request, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually caused by your check:

```
  SELECT COUNT (cus_code)
    INTO value_check
    FROM customer
   WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;
```

The above query will *never* return NULL, which is what you are checking for. If no values in the table match the parameter `temp_ccode` then the `value_check` will be 0.  This in turn means your IF statement is incorrect and this causes your error later in your code.

There's a simpler and more efficient way of doing this though. You can use [SQL%ROWCOUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS528) to find out how many rows were effected by your UPDATE. If the return value is 0 then your customer doesn't exist.

```
create or replace procedure cust_pay (
     Ptemp_ccode in number
   , Ppay_amount in number
     ) is

   l_balance number;

begin

   update customer
      set cus_balance = cus_balance - Ppay_amount
    where cus_code = Ptemp_ccode;

   if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('The customer was not found.');
   else
      select cus_balance 
        into l_balance
        from customer
       where cus_code = temp_ccode;

      if l_balance < 0 then
         dbms_output.put_line('the client owes us ' || l_balance);
      else
         dbms_output.put_line('customer new balance is ' || l_balance);
      end if;
   end if;

end;
```

There's no need to handle the NO_DATA_FOUND exception in the `select... into ...` here as you've already guaranteed that the `cus_code` exists by your UPDATE statement.

Please note the other changes I've made:

1. Different naming conventions for parameters and variables so it's clear in the code which is which.
2. Removal of the additional nested PL/SQL block, which was unnecessary.

Generally speaking you should never use `dbms_ouput.put_line` in a PL/SQL block as you *have* to be there to see what's happening. It's fine for debugging processes but is fairly useless in production code.

It's also possible to use the [RETURN statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/return_statement.htm#LNPLS01340) to avoid the nested IF statements, which I think makes the code cleaner and easier to read; though this is a judgement call.

```
create or replace procedure cust_pay (
     Ptemp_ccode in number
   , Ppay_amount in number
     ) is

   l_balance number;

begin

   update customer
      set cus_balance = cus_balance - Ppay_amount
    where cus_code = Ptemp_ccode;

   if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
      return;
   end if;

   select cus_balance 
     into l_balance
     from customer
    where cus_code = temp_ccode;

   if l_balance < 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('The client owes us ' || l_balance);
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('New balance is ' || l_balance);
   end if;

end;
```

All of this assumes that your CUSTOMER table is unique on `cus_code`.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected version of your code is here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_pay (temp_ccode IN NUMBER, pay_amount IN NUMBER) AS
   Value_check NUMBER;
   cbalance NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT Count(cus_code) 
   INTO value_check
   FROM customer
   WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

   IF value_check = 0 THEN
      Dbms_Output.put_line('the value was not FOUND');
   ELSE
      UPDATE customer
      SET cus_balance = cus_balance - pay_amount
      WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode
      RETURNING cus_balance
      INTO cbalance;

      IF cbalance < 0 THEN
         Dbms_Output.put_line('The client owes us ' || -cbalance);
      ELSE
         Dbms_Output.put_line('Customer new balance is ' || cbalance);
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I had never considered `returning into` (I don't have a need enough) +1.

Answer (score 2):

Egor Skriptunoff has just posted an [intriguing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549973/458741) and I don't want to claim any credit for the idea so I'm posting this as a different answer. It's actually possible to do everything in a single statement.

Based on the principle advocated in my other answer that it doesn't matter if you update the balance of a non-existent customer you can combine my own and Egor's answers to come up with this:

```
create or replace procedure cust_pay (
     Ptemp_ccode in number
   , Ppay_amount in number
     ) is

   l_balance number;

begin

   update customer
      set cus_balance = cus_balance - Ppay_amount
    where cus_code = Ptemp_ccode
   returning cus_balance
     into l_balance;

   if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('The customer was not found.');
   elsif l_balance < 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('The client owes us ' || l_balance);
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('New balance is ' || l_balance);
   end if;

end;
```

The benefit of doing everything in a single statement is an increase in speed. Once again you don't need to worry about the NO_DATA_FOUND exception as you're doing an update only.

Everything I said in my previous answer still holds true, `count(*)` in a `select... into...` will never return null, always a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a check before the sql query to verify parameter values

Another approach is to use `EXCEPTION NO_DATA_FOUND`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_pay (temp_ccode   IN NUMBER,
                                      pay_amount   IN NUMBER,errcode OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      Value_check   NUMBER;
      cbalance      NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT (cus_code)
        INTO value_check
        FROM customer
       WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

      IF value_check IS NULL
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('the value was not FOUND');
      ELSE
         UPDATE customer
            SET cus_balance = cus_balance - pay_amount
          WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

         SELECT cus_balance
           INTO cbalance
           FROM customer
          WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

         IF cbalance < 0
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The client owes us ' || cbalance);
         ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer new balance is ' || cbalance);
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('no data***' || SQLERRM);
      errcode := 1;
END;
```